# Display link to in table open file in classic asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have set for files in Upload folder. Also file name & file created date is stored in Database. Now
I have to bind the table with record set & provide link to download file . How I can achieve this ?  All uploaded files present in Upload Folder.  Below is my code for the same.

```
<%
    Do While NOT FileResultStatus.Eof  
    %>
   <tr>
     <td> <%= FileResultStatus.Fields("sr") %> </td>
      <%
         Dim  link
         link = Server.MapPath("Upload")
         link = link +"\" + FileResultStatus.Fields("filename")

      %>
     <td> <a href= "<%= link %> "</a>  <%= FileResultStatus.Fields("filename") %>  </td>
     <td> <%= FileResultStatus.Fields("records")  %> </td>
    </tr> 
<%

    FileResultStatus.MoveNext     
  Loop
%>
         </table>
    <%    
   FileResultStatus.Close
   Set FileResultStatus=nothing
   Connection.Close
   Set Connection=Nothing

   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem or question is. Please state more clearly what is not working.

Given that you are referencing the recordset in a correct way, there is one thing in that code that looks odd. The `Server.MapPath` function returns the physical path of Upload, i.e.something like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-application\Upload which is clearly not what you want as a href in your link. You want link like href="Upload/myfilenameFromRecordset.txt".

Answer (score 0):

The link should be a relative path to the file uploads folder, not the physical path.

In your browser just type in the location to one of the known files and use that as the link.
For example, if your download link that you type in looks like:

```
http://yourserver/Upload/filename.ext
```

then your code should be:

```
Dim  link
link = "Upload/" + FileResultStatus.Fields("filename")
```

You may have to experiment with the above or

```
link = "./Upload/" + FileResultStatus.Fields("filename")
```

depending on your setup